# ¿Cómo escuchar el evento cuando un div que tiene un scroll cambie su tamaño (scrollHeight) en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una etiqueta div a la cual le apliqué un scroll en el eje y un alto fijo.

```
<div class="exampleContenedor">
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#exampleContenedor{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 300px;
}
```

A raíz de que el contenido que tengo en el div va a ser variable necesito ejecutar ciertas acciones de javascript cuando el tamaño de este div cambie, lo que se obtener con el método **scrollHeight** pero requiero saber cuándo cambia, algún código o función que me permita escuchar este evento.

Comment: Necesitaríamos que nos indicaras como puede cambiar el tamaño este elemento para poder analizar que eventos escuchar. Porqué si por ejemplo crece porque dentro hay un textarea puedes escuchar el evento onChange para contar su tamaño, si es porqué dinámicamente añades más elementos, ahí es donde tienes que analizar el tamanño,...

Comment: Estoy manejando el framework VUE JS y pinto elementos div con clase alert de bootstrap por cada registro que obtengo en una base de datos, cada que en un textarea se agrega un comentario, éste comentario se agrega dentro de uno nuevo div, entonces de ésta manera el elemento padre que tiene el scroll cambia su tamaño dinámicamente.